# Can I call you?

Tags: north-american-english

1. Can I call you tomorrow?
2. Can't I call you tomorrow?

I know the first one is right but what about the second?  I never heard anyone say the second one unless "Why" is put in front of it.  The second doesn't sound natural to me unless its preceded by a reason like "This week is going to be really busy for me?"

When making a Can I or Can you questions, isn't it always started with a positive?

I have heard children being asked this by adults like "Boy, can't you swim?"  or "Can't you do anything right?" Obviously, this is asked mockingly or if it was seen that the child couldn't do it properly.

Comment: You give two examples of *rhetorical questions*.

Comment: So... you've answered your question yourself. A question can start with a negation, everyone has heard these many times before, and so have you. (Besides, just because you've never heard anyone say "Can't I have some tobacco salad with that lilac car", doesn't make the sentence ungrammatical. There are more grammatical sentences than we can possibly hear in all our lifetimes combined.)

Answer (score 1):

The second one is correct if you have to believe that the other person might not want you to call tomorrow:

**--You can call me the day after tomorrow.**

**--Can't I call you tomorrow?**

**--I'll be hard to reach/very busy/unavailable tomorrow.**  Or **--Of course, you can.**